# Magento2 REST Search "Query does not exists"

Tags: rest, search, magento-2.0

I am on Mangento 2.0.3 CE and I'm trying to call the `/search` REST API.

With this request :

```
/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%test%&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

I get this error :

```
{
  "message": "Query quick_search_container does not exist",
  "trace": "#0 vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Mapper.php(94): Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Request\\Mapper->mapQuery('quick_search_co...')\n#1 vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Builder.php(183): Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Request\\Mapper->getRootQuery()\n#2 vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Builder.php(141): Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Request\\Builder->convert(Array)\n#3 vendor/magento/framework/Search/Search.php(71): Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Request\\Builder->create()\n#4 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Search->search(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Api\\Search\\SearchCriteria))\n#5 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(265): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#6 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(160): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#7 var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#9 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#10 index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#11 {main}"
}
```

If I remove the `search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container` from the query I get this error `Request name not defined.`

I have one category "CatTest" set and one simple product "ProdTest" which should appear in the result.

Anyone knows how to resolve this error ?

[EDIT]

After digging a bit more I found out that in the class `vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Builder.php` l.137, the `clean` method whipout the `$data` var. 
Which then provoc the given exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem came from my request which was wrong.

For the search API a correct request is (to be converted to a GET request) :

```
{
    "searchCriteria" : {
        "requestName": "quick_search_container",
        "filterGroups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "search_term",
                        "value": "*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "current_page": 1,
        "page_size": 20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who got here and didn't get what the answer mean here you go:

```
http://your-siteurl.com/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=Life
&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at
&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC
&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10
```

Here I m searching by name = Like. We use the quick_search_container. Important thing is the search_term as we can use that for searching with quick search and not by using the searchCriteria.

You can check file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml

for more information